# Localization using multiple resx files

Tags: .net, localization, resx, resourcemanager

My web application is handling localization via resource file placed in a satellite assembly using ResourceManager. Since the application is growing I would like to split resx file into multiple files (for each language), but on the client side, seems that I have to create a ResourceManager instance for each file that I want to read from. Is there any way to wrap multiple resx files into single one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using websites (ASP.NET Web Sites Project Template) you may want to do this: `HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(classKey, resourceKey)` where the classKey is the name of your .resx file and resourceKey is the localized string in your resource.

If you are using WebApplications and you have your resources as a separate project (C# library), you may want to take a look at this code:

```
public class SatelliteResourceManager
    {
        private const string Resources = "Resources";
        private readonly string _assemblyName;

        public SatelliteResourceManager(string assemblyName)
        {
            _assemblyName = assemblyName;
        }

        public Assembly Assembly { get { return Assembly.Load(_assemblyName); } }

        protected IEnumerable<Type> ResourceTypes
        {
            get
            { 
                return Assembly.GetTypes().Where(a => a.IsClass && a.Namespace == Resources);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<ResourceManager> GetAllManagers()
        {
            foreach (var manager in ResourceTypes)
            {
                yield return (ResourceManager) manager.GetProperty("ResourceManager").GetValue(this, null);
            }
        }

        public string GetGlobalResource(string classKey, string resourceKey, string fallback)
        {
            var manager = GetAllManagers().FirstOrDefault(m => m.BaseName.EndsWith(classKey, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (manager != null) return manager.GetString(resourceKey);
            return fallback;
        }
    }
```

You need to instance the class by passing a parameter with your resource project assembly name, you can get this information from project properties.
I have also added a field "Resources" this should be useful if you decided to override the default namespace of each .resx file, be aware you may want to extend this class to allow multiple "namespaces" for your .resx files (screenshot attached)

[image: Using Custom Namespaces]

Comment: Hi, Then how can we use it with a @inject IStringLocalizer<SatelliteResourceManager> _L ? I mean to have something like @_L["about.description"]